# In matplotlib which function is used to show merged points along with colorbars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code I have three columns E, W and KL, each having dimension 1300. I want to use KL values as colorbar and E and W as x and y axis respectively. With the scattered plot . I want them to appear as merging points showing a smooth plot but I don't know what kind of function in matplotlib is suitable for this purpose?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import math
import os

from matplotlib import cm


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
data=np.loadtxt("./dos_bins60_distribution_bins60")
print(data[:,0].shape)

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('BuGn')
E=data[:,0]
W=data[:,1]
KL=data[:,2]
print(KL.shape)
im=data[:,0:2]
print("im shape: ",im.shape)
sc = plt.scatter(E, W, c=KL, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=cm)
plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.savefig("./Phase")`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqmMG.png)

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: `plt.tricontourf(E, W, KL, levels=np.linspace(0,1,100), cmap=cm)`

Comment: Yes ,plt.tricontourf exactly generates the expected result. Only one problem is left that this command drawa a line at the boundaries that I want to omit from the plot. Can I do that?

Comment: Maybe the boundary line comes from the data? It is hard to see without data nor image.

Comment: I have one more confusion. With tricontourf command I want to assing colors according to KL array comprising 1300 values.  Even if I use levels= np.linspace(0,1,100), color corresponding to maximum value i.e.,1 is dark blue that is not visible in the plot. What I want to say is that the values of colorbar and the actual figure are different. My reputation is less than 10 so  that's why I can not attach plot.

Comment: What if I want to use plt.imshow  command but this function demand Z that is defined in terms of x and y. How should I select that function?